# Getting this twitter's api response {"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]} solution please

Tags: reactjs, api, twitter, postman

i want to use twitter's api to get tweets of public pages.
i am using this GET api( https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=nasa&result_type=popular ) but i am getting this:-
please help thanks.

{
"errors": [

```
    {

        "code": 215,

        "message": "Bad Authentication data."

    }

]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide authentication for this endpoint, as per [twitter API docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html). For tweets search endpoint it is sufficient to use application-only authentication, so you will need to get bearer token.

Refer to [authentication guide](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/application-only) for details on how to properly do it.

Comment: i am using 0Auth 1.0 and added all the credentials but still its giviing the same error.

Comment: You are most likely still missing some auth headers with your request, judging by [Twitter docs on response codes](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/response-codes). Note that there are several headers required, as per [creating OAuth 1 signature](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/creating-a-signature.html) and [authorizing requests](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/authorizing-a-request). If you did everything and still getting that error, try switching to OAuth 2, as it usually better supported nowadays.